# How do you set a Tensorflow 2 Keras optimizer to a state, before you've applied grads with it?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm working at a slightly lower-level of Keras than the Model fit API. I  would like to be able to set the state of a newly constructed optimizer to the state of it from previous training.

The `get_weights` and `set_weights` methods seem promising; they just return and receive numpy arrays or standard scalar data for the state of the optimizer. However, the problem is you cannot `set_weights` if the weights have not yet been created, and as far as I can tell, the only *public* way they get created is on the first call to `apply_gradients`.

For example, the following fails because `opt2` will not have its weights created.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

opt1 = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
opt2 = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

# dummy data
x = np.array([[-1, 1], [1, 1]])
y = np.array([[-1], [1]])

# do one optimization step
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss = (layer(x) - y)**2
grads = tape.gradient(loss, layer.trainable_weights)
opt1.apply_gradients(zip(grads, layer.trainable_weights))

# copy state to optimizer 2
opt2.set_weights(opt1.get_weights())  # this fails!
```

Lets assume I do have on hand the relevant model weights on which the optimizer operates. What is the right way restore state? Based on the implementation of the `apply_gradients` method, it seems like this is the path:

```
_ = opt2.iterations  # must be called to make this weight appear
opt2._create_hypers()
opt2._create_slots(layer.trainable_weights)

# now we can safely set weights
opt2.set_weights(opt1.get_weights())
```

But that feels really hacky to me and prone to fail if implementation details change at a future point. Are there better approaches that I'm missing?